# Programmatically Create an Array of Containers in TestStand

Tags: c#, teststand

**Problem**

I'm trying to create an array of containers in c# to pass back to TestStand as test results, and there doesn't appear to be an easy way to accomplish this task.

**Motivation**

In c# I have results contained in `List<Dictionary<string,object>>` from my test system and I'd like to have those results show up in my test report.  The `Dictionary<string,object>` has a variable number of elements of different types.

**Attempted Solutions**

If given:

```
var result = sequenceContext.AsPropertyObject().EvaluateEx(destination, EvaluationOptions.EvalOption_NoOptions);
```

Where

- sequenceContext is NationalInstruments.TestStand.Interop.API.SequenceContext
- destination is where I'd like my results to be saved in my TestStand report, i.e. Step.Result.TestResultDestination

I've tried a few different methods to add an array of containers to `result`, such as:

```
var newPropertyObject = sequenceContext.Engine.NewPropertyObject(PropertyValueTypes.PropValType_Container, true, string.Empty, PropertyOptions.PropOption_InsertIfMissing);
result.SetPropertyObject("TestResultDestination", PropertyOptions.PropOption_InsertIfMissing, newPropertyObject);
result.SetFlags("TestResultDestination", PropertyOptions.PropOption_NoOptions, PropertyFlags.PropFlags_IncludeInReport | PropertyFlags.PropFlags_IsMeasurementValue);
```

Which adds the array of containers to my result, however any attempt to then insert an  element into the array of containers results in an exception.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was close, I was missing a few key steps:

```
 if (!result.Exists("TestResultDestination", 0))
 {
       //once we have added this element do not add it again, it will overwrite the other array elements
       var newPropertyObject = sequenceContext.Engine.NewPropertyObject(PropertyValueTypes.PropValType_Container, true, string.Empty, PropertyOptions.PropOption_InsertIfMissing);
       //for my example I only need 5 elements, set the dimension of the array                                        
       newPropertyObject.SetNumElements(5, 0);
       result.SetPropertyObject("TestResultDestination", PropertyOptions.PropOption_InsertIfMissing, newPropertyObject);
       result.SetFlags(newKey, PropertyOptions.PropOption_NoOptions, PropertyFlags.PropFlags_IncludeInReport | PropertyFlags.PropFlags_IsMeasurementValue);
  }
```

One can then proceed to work with an element in the array by using array syntax, i.e. `TestResultDestination[0]` to store the actual results.